# How to get multi email from one form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, email

I created a registration form with multi participant name registering in one form.

It successfully inserts the participant's details to database and send to admin's email.

My issue is I am only receiving one participants' detail in email.

Sample: If I register 3 participants I am only getting the third participant's details in the email.

I am not getting 1st and 2nd participant details.

How to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

[Please find the image below on multi participants form][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJrTf.png

```
        $sql = "
    INSERT INTO testing (name , designation, company_name, mobile, nature_business, person_incharge, person_email, person_mobile, address, tel, hrdf, sme, coursename, price, date, month, year) 
        
        VALUES 
        
        (
        '".$name."' 

        ,'".$_POST['date']."'
        ,'".$_POST['month']."'
        ,'".$_POST['year']."'        
        )";
        
        $mysqli->query($sql);
    }
}


    




    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
    $mail->addaddress(');
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject=''.$_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body=
'<h3>
    <b>Applying for Public Training Course
</h3>   
    <br><br>
    <p>
    <b>Participant Name:</b></br> '.$name.'
    <br>
    <b>Date:</b></br> '.$_POST['date'].' (Date), '.$_POST['month'].' (Month), '.$_POST['year'].' (Year)
</p>';
    if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Message could not sent!";
    }
    else{
    echo"<script>
        alert('We received your message! We will reply to your message as soon as possible.'); 
        window.history.go(-1);
     </script>";
    }
}
```

Below is my form

```
<form action="addmore.php" method="post">

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Participant/s Details</p>
    <label class="small">* You may add more participants by clicking "Add More" button</label>
    </div> 
    
    <table class="tablecustom" id="dynamic_field"> 
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control name_list" required/>  

        <input type="text" name="designation[]" placeholder="Enter Designation" class="form-control name_list" required />    
                        
        <input type="number" name="mobile[]" placeholder="Enter Mobile" class="form-control name_list" required /> 
                        
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button> 
    </div>
    </table>      
</div>

                

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Company Name</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Enter Company Name" class="form-control name_list" required/></td> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Company Address</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Company Address" class="form-control name_list" required/>
    </div>      

    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Company Tel No</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="EG: 0312345678" class="form-control name_list" required/>
    </div>      


    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Nature of Business</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="text" name="nature" placeholder="Enter Nature of Business" class="form-control name_list" required/>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Contact Person</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="text" name="person" placeholder="Enter Person in Charge" class="form-control name_list" required/>
    </div> 
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Contact Person's Email</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Person in Email" class="form-control name_list" required/>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>Contact Person's Mobile</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="number" name="personmobile" placeholder="Enter Person Mobile Number" class="form-control name_list" required/>
    </div>     


    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>HRDF Registered Company</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">  
    
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="hrdf" value="Yes" required>
    <label for="male">Yes</label>    
    
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="hrdf" value="No">
    <label for="female">No</label> 
    </div>   
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    <p>SME Company</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-sm-8">             
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="sme" value="Yes" required>
    <label for="male">Yes</label>    
    
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="sme" value="No">
    <label for="female">No</label> 
    </div>       


    <div class="col-sm-4">             
    </div> 

<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sys_course WHERE sys_course_id = '$id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
?> 
    <input type="hidden" class="form" name="coursename" value="<?php echo $row['sys_course_topic']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="form" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['sys_course_price']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="form" name="date" value="<?php echo $row['sys_course_date']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="form" name="month" value="<?php echo $row['sys_course_month']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="form" name="year" value="<?php echo $row['sys_course_year']; ?>"/>
<?php } } ?>


    <div class="col-sm-8">  
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LehlekZAAAAAATkbl5lKz156LPq_2b5MjGVVrp1"></div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
    </div>
</div>           

</form>
```

Comment: using $_POST['name'][0], [1], [2]. Your html input `<input type="text" name="name[]" />`

Comment: So now that you have posted your actual domain and email information, as well as posting code that can easily be victimized by sql injection, perhaps you might want to read up on using prepared statements.  As for your actual question, you don't even provide the form, so how can anyone answer your question?

Comment: @FSodic I've updated my question with my form code

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things in your sample code that are problematic, but since your question is specifically about what happens when you use array notation in an html form, as in `name="name[]`, I focused on that.

What php does is turn those elements into an array in the $_POST.

These are disconnected variables ('name', 'designation', 'mobile'), which could be an issue if the user doesn't fill the form out as you expect.

```
// Participants
if (count($_POST['name']) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['name'] as $name) {
       $designation = $_POST['designation'][$i];
       $mobile = $_POST['mobile'][$i];
       // Do something with this info, perhaps adding to email body?
       $email .= "$name: $designation ($mobile)" . PHP_EOL;
       $i++;
    }

}
```

Note that your form only expects one email address for the company contact and not multiples.